# Longitudinal study - generalised linear mixed model - dealing with very wide confidence intervals due to sparsity in the outcome

Tags: confidence-interval, multilevel-analysis, sparse, glmmtmb

I am conducting a treatment evaluation using administrative data. It is a population-based study of all people diagnosed with a specific disorder in two calendar years (*N* = 2300). I have run a GLMM using the `glmmTMB` package in `R` using the following code:

```
glmmTMB(y ~ T*P*IG + offset(log(exposure)) + (1 | id),
weights = wts,
data = df,
family = poisson)
```

where `T` is a numeric variable denoting the time in months (0-41), `P` is a binary variable defining the pre- / post-intervention periods, `IG` is a binary variable denoting the intervention (comparison) group, and `exposure` is the number of days at risk per month.

The confidence intervals for the RR returned for `P*IG` are very wide (e.g., 0.02 - 1300), presumably because the outcome (an adverse event) is rare. Less than 2% of all patients experienced an adverse event at any time point, and the vast majority of the observations have zero events.

While I have come across a number of sources citing potential reasons for such wide confidence intervals, there seems to be relatively little guidance **on how to deal with them**. If I am incorrect in this statement, forgive my ignorance. If there is some truth to it, what are some potential *remedies* or alternative approaches to modelling such data?

Comment: I suspect the answer is collect more data unwelcome though that must be. If it is administrative data it may be impossible anyway. I assume you are including T as continuous rather than a factor.

Comment: @mdewey Unfortunately, I don't think more data will resolve the problem. I think the outcome is just quite rare in this population. T is continuous (0-41 months). I have edited my post to reflect this.

Comment: @C_H more data with more events of interest would mitigate the problem. Having 1 million observations with a total of 2000 occurrences is absolutely better than 2000 with 40 occurrences of interest. (Disregarding feasibility...)

Comment: @mdewey My apologies. Beyond "small" samples, I thought the issue with sparsity was simply that the ratio of occurrences : non-occurrences is too low. Assuming the manual collection of more data is not feasible, is some kind of simulation process based on the parameters of this dataset a viable option? Or is this just wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to bring together information from comments here.

The issue is partly the sparsity of the data and partly the sample size (in terms of events, there are zillions of non-events). In such situations there is not much one can do if the option of collecting more data is closed off. One possible way of extracting at least something is to use a less complex model either by removing the three way interaction or even all the interactions apart from the one of scientific/clinical interest (I*PG). Whether that would be acceptable is moving beyond the limits of statistics to encompass scientific/clinical concerns.